# Remove "$" before ASP.Net RangeValidator script executes

Tags: asp.net, currency, rangevalidator

How can I force the input's onchange script to run *before* the RangeValidator's script?

I want to prevent a failed validation when the user enters a dollar sign or comma.

```
function cleanUp(str) {
    re = /^\$|,/g;
    return str.replace(re, ""); // remove "$" and ","
}

<input type="text" id="salary" runat="server"
onchange="this.value=cleanUp(this.value)" />

<asp:RangeValidator ID="salaryValidator" 
    runat="server" ErrorMessage="Invalid Number"
    ControlToValidate="salary" Type="Double" />
```

**UPDATE:** 
I decided to use a CustomValidator that checks the range and uses a currency RegEx.  Thanks Michael Kniskern.

```
function IsCurrency(sender, args) {
    var input = args.Value;

    // Check for currency formatting.
    // Expression is from http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=70
    re = /^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(.[0-9][0-9])?$/;
    isCurrency = input.match(re);

    if (isCurrency) {
        // Convert the string to a number.
        var number = parseFloat(CleanUp(input));
        if (number != NaN) {
            // Check the range.
            var min = 0;
            var max = 1000000;
            if (min <= number && max >= number) {
                // Input is valid.
                args.IsValid = true;
                return;
            }
        }
    }

    // Input is not valid if we reach this point.
    args.IsValid = false;
    return;
}

function CleanUp(number) {
    re = /^\$|,/g;
    return number.replace(re, ""); // remove "$" and ","
}       

<input type="text" id="salary" runat="server" />

<asp:CustomValidator ID="saleryValidator" ControlToValidate="salary" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="Invalid Number" ClientValidationFunction="IsCurrency" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried using a CustomerValidator control and combined the functionality of the JS cleanup methods and the RangeValidator method.

Answer (score 3):

I think I can improve on that.  This makes commas and cents digits optional:

```
^\$?([0-9]{1,3},?([0-9]{3},?)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(\.[0-9]{0,2})?$
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this by registering the script; however why not use a Regular Expression Validator to make sure the input is proper?

Also, the Range validator executes on the fields onBlur js event, not on change.

Comment: RangeValidator restricts the salary from 0 to 1,000,000 (but I left that out of the markup in my post).  This could probably be done within Regex, but the code is more readable using a range validator for that.

Answer (score 0):

Just noticed that you have a '.' for the decimal point, but that means the regex will accept any character in that spot. You should use `\.` for that decimal point.

```
/^\$?([0-9]{1,3},([0-9]{3},)*[0-9]{3}|[0-9]+)(\.[0-9][0-9])?$/
```