# Check textbox validation

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation

i have to check a textbox control for validation

Conditions:

1. contain value 0 to 1000 upto 2 decimal places( 1.00,85.23,1000.00)
2. after 2 decimal points user wont be able to enter any more zeros.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">

   var regex = /\d{0,4}([\.])\d{0,2}/;
   function keyUP()
   {   
         var t = document.getElementById('<%=TextBoxPayRate.ClientID%>').value;
         if (!regex.test(t)) 
         {
            alert("not matching");
         }
   }
   </script>

   <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxPayRate" runat="server"  onkeyup="keyUP();"></asp:TextBox>
   ```

Comment: Others may or may not be willing to be code factories for you but not me. Show me what you have tried so far!

Comment: @Aman:First: what is your **problem**???

Comment: the test is failing everytime. if i enter 1 alert appears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you should be able to use/modify the updated code on this post to acheive what you require.

[Remove "$" before ASP.Net RangeValidator script executes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/354313/remove-before-asp-net-rangevalidator-script-executes)